# Capture all data between two braces

Tags: regex, go

Trying to read all data enclosed within two curly braces. I suspect my regex fails because it cannot match newlines. Link to source in go playground: http://play.golang.org/p/uNjd01CL8Z

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    x := `
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address 10.11.0.1;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.0.0;
}
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address 10.11.0.2;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.0.0;
}
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address 10.11.0.2;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.0.0;
}`

    re := regexp.MustCompile(`{(.+)?}`)
    fmt.Println(re.FindAllString(x, -1))

}
```

Comment: You might probably wanna use `\{(.*?)\}`.

Comment: @CPanda Your tip doesn't work. The error with my regex is that it doesn't match newlines. The solution given by tonisuter works.

Comment: You can also use `re := regexp.MustCompile(\`{[\s\S]*?}\`)`

Comment: @linuxfan I am a python guy. I could have told you use the `re.DOTALL` flag. But this won't make sense for Go. Sorry if I trespassed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    x := `
lease {
    interface "eth0";
    fixed-address 10.11.0.1;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.0.0;
}
lease {
    interface "eth0";
    fixed-address 10.11.0.2;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.0.0;
}
lease {
    interface "eth0";
    fixed-address 10.11.0.2;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.0.0;
}`

    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?s){.*?}`)
    fmt.Println(re.FindAllString(x, -1))
}
```

I changed two things. The `(?s)` flag means that it will match newlines as for `.` wildcards as well. And the `.*?` means that it will rather match fewer than more characters between the braces. If you would use `.*`, it would match the outer pair of braces instead.

Here's the link to the documentation of the regex syntax used for Go regular expressions: https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

Comment: Right on @tonisuter. Thanks